# valgrind reports invalid read when mallocing

Tags: c, valgrind

I am trying to implement a function that uses malloc in it. When I run it using valgrind, it reports the following errors like this:

```
Invalid read of size 1
==11870==    at 0x4C33DC7: strcmp (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==11870==    by 0x10A864: testFormatAsHex (apintTests.c:212)
==11870==    by 0x109351: main (apintTests.c:72)
==11870==  Address 0x55cd4e1 is 0 bytes after a block of size 1 alloc'd
==11870==    at 0x4C2FB0F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==11870==    by 0x10B989: apint_format_as_hex (apint.c:225)
==11870==    by 0x10A84D: testFormatAsHex (apintTests.c:212)
==11870==    by 0x109351: main (apintTests.c:72)
```

And there are a lot of invalid writes due to malloc. I really don't understand this, what is the reason of malloc creating invalid writes? I didn't allocate temp_rep anywhere other than in this function, and I made sure to free each temp_rep after testing.

```
//loop over the array, transforming each u64 number to hex;placing it in array
  //and realloc returning array when placing a char in it
  long length=ap->length;
  int i;
  int hex_pos=0;
  //store the largest without appending zeroes
  if (ap->bin_string[length-1]==0UL){
    char* temp_rep=malloc(sizeof(char));
     temp_rep[hex_pos]='0';
     return temp_rep;
  }
  else{
   
    int most_sig_bits=ceil(log2(apint_get_bits(ap,length-1)));
    int temp_length=ceil((float)most_sig_bits/4);
    char* temp_rep=malloc(temp_length*sizeof(char));
    uint64_t lar_val=ap->bin_string[length-1];
    sprintf(temp_rep,"%lx",lar_val);
  
    //for rest of the terms in array, store them padded
    for(i=length-2;i>=0;i--){
      char *hex_rep=malloc(16*sizeof(char));
      uint64_t val=ap->bin_string[i];
      sprintf(hex_rep,"%016lx",val);
      temp_rep=realloc(temp_rep,sizeof(temp_rep)+sizeof(hex_rep));  
      temp_rep=strcat(temp_rep,hex_rep);
      free(hex_rep);
      }
  return temp_rep;
  }
  
}
```

Comment: The read problem may be because you aren't null-terminating your string properly.  Your write problems may be because you aren't remembering to allocate enough space for the null byte at the end of the string.  If you're using Valgrind correctly, it will report line numbers which makes it easy to fix the problems.  The trouble is not in `malloc()`; it is in the way you are using `malloc()`.  You also need to read about creating an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 — or MRE or whatever name SO now uses). We need whole functions to help you.

Comment: Valgrind reports invalid read in `strcmp`, not in `malloc`.  The problem should be at `apintTests.c:212` line of code.

Answer (score 0):

The invalid write isn't due to `malloc`.  The message says it's due to a `strcmp` call that's working with a buffer returned from `malloc`.

It says it reads past the end of a malloc'ed buffer whose size is 1.  That looks suspicious for a string.  If you look at where you allocated the memory:

```
  int hex_pos=0;
  //store the largest without appending zeroes
  if (ap->bin_string[length-1]==0UL){
    char* temp_rep=malloc(sizeof(char));
     temp_rep[hex_pos]='0';
     return temp_rep;
  }
```

You allocate 1 byte and store the character `'0'` there.  But apparently `temp_rep` is supposed to be string, which means you didn't null terminate it.  You need to allocate one additional byte for the null terminator and set is:

```
     char* temp_rep=malloc(2);
     temp_rep[0]='0';
     temp_rep[1]=0;
     return temp_rep;
```

You have similar issues in the `else` block where you don't leave space for the null terminator, and you're using `sizeof` on `temp_rep` and `hex_rep` (which gets you the size of the pointers, not the string they contain) instead of `strlen`.